# Is opinions of (other domain) experts that support scriptures on-topic?

Tags: discussion

It is well known that several modern experts of different domains do **supporting** comments about Hinduism.

Consider the following questions

> Are there any modern biologists other than X supported ayurveda?
>
> Did any quantum physics researcher talk about Advaitha vedanta and
> what are their arguments for supporting it? [!](https://www.fritjofcapra.net/heisenberg-and-tagore/)
>
> Are there any experts like [C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ugyrzr5Ds8o) talked about the uniqueness of
> Hinduism regarding astronomy?

All the questions are asking for expert opinions that are not against scriptures. Is it allowed to ask such questions on our main site?

I personally feel that it will be okay to ask such questions assuming common sense of questioner.

Comment: Though how tempting it looks, I am disagreeing at the moment. Such questions are so many that eventually this site will lose the defined scope and becomes something else. I think such questions are gratefully welcome at Skeptics.SE.

Comment: They are experts in other fields of study **not Hinduism**. So, their opinions must not be treated as authoritative on this site. Just like opinions of Mahatma Gandhi, Irawati Karwe, H.D.Sankalia, James Talboys Wheeler etc. are not